# Сдвиг элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: delphi, массивы

Есть двумерный массив. Мне нужно последний (второй) элемент массива переставить на место первого и сократить длину массива на 1, убрав последний элемент.

```
var
  LIndex, L_Last: integer;
  PrArr_ListFile: array of array of string;
begin
for LIndex := 0 to 1 do
begin
SetLength(PrArr_ListFile, Length(PrArr_ListFile) + 1, 2);
PrArr_ListFile[LIndex, 0] := IntToStr(LIndex + 100);
PrArr_ListFile[LIndex, 1] := IntToStr(LIndex + 120);
end;

L_Last := high(PrArr_ListFile);
LIndex := 0;
move(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex + 1], PrArr_ListFile[LIndex], (L_Last - LIndex) * sizeof(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex + 1]));
setLength(PrArr_ListFile, L_Last, 2);
```

Но я ошибаюсь в сдвиге (функция `Move`) - у меня получается заменить первый элемент вторым, и после `setLength(PrArr_ListFile, L_Last, 2);` 
у меня получается массив `(('', ''))`

Где я сделал ошибку?

Comment: А можно наверно проще поступить:    LIndex := 0;

    PrArr_ListFile[LIndex] := PrArr_ListFile[LIndex+1];
    setLength(PrArr_ListFile, Length(PrArr_ListFile)-1, 2);;

Comment: +1 за вопрос в его текущей формулировке. Ясно что код неправильный - копируется только указатель, но интересно почему именно это вызывает крах приложения.

Comment: @KromStern потому, что методом `move` код делает непонятно что. Куда указывает `PrArr_ListFile[LIndex + 1]` если массив двумерный? Где второй индекс? Чему равно `sizeof(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex + 1])`?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci: Насколько мне известно, массив это указатель, и соответственно размер его равен 4 (что легко проверяется). Вопрос в другом, что такое ломается при затирке указателя предыдущего индекса?

Comment: @KromStern уточняйте задачу. Вы хотите убрать последний элемент по второму индексу или по первому.

Comment: В конце в `SetLength` вы опять задаете массиву размер 2х2, Возьмите в качестве примера другой массив (6x6 подойдет) и посмотрите как будет работать с ним ваш алгоритм.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci: интерес чисто академический, повторюсь: "Ясно что код неправильный - копируется только указатель, но интересно **почему именно** это вызывает крах приложения"

Answer (score 1):

Под вашу формулировку задачи подходит вот такой вариант:

```
for LIndex := 0 to Length(PrArr_ListFile) - 1 do
begin
  PrArr_ListFile[LIndex, 0] := PrArr_ListFile[LIndex, Length(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex]) - 1];
  SetLength(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex], Length(PrArr_ListFile[LIndex]) - 1);
end;
```

Сразу после цикла заполнения массива вставляйте приведенный выше код.